# make PHP run file when viewing any folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, directory

I know this must be something around .htaccess or php.ini.

If a site visitor views **ANY** folder I want to automatically run a script listing the files in it (file_read.php).

But I only want the file_read.php to be in my root folder.

Can someone point me please?

Thanks.

Comment: How does `file_read.php` get the name of the folder to read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not so long ago I had similar problem and ended with `.htaccess` like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}index.php !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}index.html !-f
RewriteRule (.*/) file_read.php?dirpath=/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^$ file_read.php?dirpath=/ [L]

</IfModule>
```

Some explanation why like this:

1. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d` - to make it work only on directories
2. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}index.php !-f` - do not list directories containiing index file
3. `RewriteRule (.*/) file_read.php?dirpath=/$1` - note the ending slash, without it entering `http://server.com/directory` (no trailing slash) was redirected to something like `http://server.com/directory/file_read.php?dirpath=directory`, not exactly what we wanted.
4. `RewriteRule ^$ file_read.php?dirpath=/` - after adding trailing slash to rule above, directory lister stopped working for root directory (`http://server.com/`) so this line fixes it

Answer (score 7):

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule (.*) file_read.php?dirpath=$1
```

Comment: ...or this is probably better than mine. +1.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ file_read.php?dir=$1 [L]
```

Every request where the last character of the path is a `/` gets `file_read.php`, and the path requested will be available to `file_read.php` in `$_GET['dir']`.

Comment: there is -d directive -"is directory"

Your solution is wrong because there will be no 404 error on not existing directory

Comment: I know, I forgot about it and yours is definitely the better answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way: Just remove any index file (e.g. index.php, index.html) and make sure you don't have a DirectoryIndex directive in .htaccess pointing to any existing file in the folder. Then when you view the folder, you will see all of the files in that folder. Of course, that doesn't use any read_file.php script to do it; it just lets the directory index itself.

Another way: As DaveRandom and Piotr Szymkowski showed, you can use .htaccess to route all calls to all directory to the read_file.php file, passing the current directory path as an argument to that file. Then, using **readdir()** (see the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) for usage), you can list out the files within it.